# How can I subscribe to an activemq topic with just read rights?

Tags: activemq-classic

I have been trying to configure my activemq server so that anonymous clients can just subscribe to topics (they would not be able to create nor publish to topics).

I've set the rights accordingly on my broker configuration:

```xml
<plugins>
    <simpleAuthenticationPlugin anonymousAccessAllowed="true">
        <users>
            <authenticationUser username="system" password="manager"
                groups="anonymous,admins"/>
        </users>
    </simpleAuthenticationPlugin>


  <!--  Lets configure a destination based authorization mechanism -->
  <authorizationPlugin>
    <map>
      <authorizationMap>
        <authorizationEntries>
          <authorizationEntry queue=">" read="admins,anonymous" write="admins" admin="admins" />

          <authorizationEntry topic=">" read="admins,anonymous"  write="admins" admin="admins" />

        </authorizationEntries>
      </authorizationMap>
    </map>
  </authorizationPlugin>

</plugins>
```

and I have been using code below for subscribing based on a couple of tutorials I found on the web. However this topic consumer code, and all the ones I've found, creates an activemq topic to bind to (event if the topic already exists) and as a consequence it will only be authorized if I give admin rights to the user as well... **Is there a way to subscribe to the topic without creating it?**

```java
     ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory(connectionString);
     connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
     session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
     destination = session.createTopic(topicName);
     MessageConsumer consumer = null;
     consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);
     consumer.setMessageListener(this);
     connection.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

The topic has to be created by someone in order to be read from. The alternative to creation of demand is to create the topic through a `<destinations>` block within the `<broker>` block:

```
<destinations>
    <topic physicalName="someTopic"/>
</destinations>
```

When you say "creates an activemq topic to bind to (event if the topic already exists)" you might be seeing [advisory topics](http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html) being created on demand (which is normal). You should add the following to your authorization config:

```
<authorizationEntry topic="ActiveMQ.Advisory.>" 
    read="admins" 
    write="admins,anonymous" 
    admin="admins,anonymous" />
```

Comment: What I mean by existing topic is a topic which has been previously created by an authorized java client (with admin rights), and in my case, with messages being published to it. And then, a subscriber to connect to that topic which already exists and subscribe to it. The problem is that I could only subscribe to that existing topic on Java by first calling `destination = session.createTopic(topicName) ;` and for being able to do that, I have to give admin rights to that user while Id like him to have just read rights

Comment: In actuality the createTopic method does not produce any communications with the Broker so you are free to call it from you client code even if it has only read access.  Things would fail only when the client then went on to subscribe or produce to a destination that doesn't exist in which case an exception would be thrown.  You should think of createTopic and createQueue only as local factory methods for the objects they return.